# number of elements in a static array of a predefined size

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
int a[100];
```

I am filling only the first 4 elements in this array:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
```

When I do `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`  it returns 100.

Is there a way I can get number of elements to which I have assinged a value and thus filtering out the remaining 96 unassigned elements?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All elements must be assigned to something, thus the array always has 100 elements. If you can ensure all the elements are initialized to a special value which means "unassigned" to you (e.g. -1), you can work it out like this:

```
// fill the array with a special value which means "uninitialized"
const int special_uninitialized = -1;
std::fill(&a[0], &a[100], special_uninitialized);

// set up your values
a[0] = 1;

// count
std::size_t uninitialized_count = std::count(&a[0], &a[100], special_uninitialized);
std::size_t initialized_count = 100 - uninitialized_count;
```

If you just want to know how many elements are in an array, you have these options:

1. Don't use an array, use `std::vector`, which has a `size()` function, and is generally a better choice than a basic array
2. Keep track of the element count yourself, in a separate variable
3. Use the special "unassigned" value as described above, and use `std::find` to find the first one, and work out how many are there by subtracting the address of the zeroth element from that. This is a pretty ugly solution.

For a beginner, `std::vector` is a much better choice. You can use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(17);
vec.push_back(23);
vec.push_back(5);

int x = vec[0]; // x will be 17
vec[0] = 40; // set element 0

size_t s = vec.size(); // s will be 3
```

Comment: +1: While 'No' is a valid answer, using `std::vector` is far more useful!

Comment: Just being a pedant, but "All elements must be assigned to something" isn't strictly true. A POD-type will have no value, because it is uninitialized.

Comment: @GMan: you're right of course, I meant "all elements must have some value", I was just trying to state that in terms of the OP's question. But as I read recently elsewhere on Stack Overflow, we need to be pedantic if we're going to use this language without blowing everything up ;-)

Comment: There is one point of contention between the `vector` and a static array though. With a static array, you may use any index whereas with a vector using an index superior or equal to size is undefined behavior... so I would definitely recommend `at` to users. It's a shame that the operator is unsafe and the verbose version is safe, I would have preferred the latter since programmers are lazy :/

Answer (score 8):

No.  Nothing keeps track of that.

Answer (score 7):

No. Either use a data structure, such as `Vector`, that keeps track of length, or pre-fill the array with a value which cannot ever occur as a real value, and test for that value and end of array while looping from start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're a beginner (and thus not jumping into the STL), here's an example of what @Mitch is talking about:

```
char *Names[100] = {}; // zero init

Names[0] = "hello";
Names[1] = "world";

for (int n = 0; n < 100 && Names[n] != 0; ++n)
    if (!Names[n])
        break;

printf("# of entries: %d", n);
```

Nowadays you would only do this if had to keep memory usage to an absolute minimum.

Comment: You can simplify the initialization and zeroing to `char *Names[100] = {};`

Comment: There's plenty of good reasons for beginners to start with the STL. Stroustrup has an essay about this on his website. Then again, there's plenty more good reasons for beginners to avoid C++ altogether :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an associative container like [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) in this case? It allows you to test wether it contains an entry with a given key using [`std::map::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/):

```
std::map<size_t, int> myMap;
myMap[0] = 1;
// ...
bool contains = myMap.find(0) != myMap.end();
```

Comment: I don't see any +1 ;) Not that its important though. @cppb

Answer (score 0):

In the message title you called your array "static". If this is indeed an array with static storage duration, then its elements are zero-initialized by default at program startup. Since the "assigned" values you used in your example are non-zero, you can determine how many elements you have assigned by finding the first zero element in the array. Of course, this will only work when the "assigned" values are guaranteed to be non-zero, i.e. if zero value can be thought of as a *reserved* value.

Answer (score 0):

I think using boost::optional as array type can solve the problem:

```
boost::optional<int> a[100];
```

So, you can check if element is set like this:

```
if (! a[i]) {   // element not set
}
else {  // element not set
}
```

Using boost:array instead of bare static array may be good idea too.